# Algebraic element proof

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Definition-Lemma: Let $F$ be a subfield of a field $L$. An element $a\in L$ is called algebraic over $F$ if one of the following equivalent conditions hold:

1. $f(a)=0$, for an non-zero polynomial $f(X)\in F[X]$
2. elements $1,a,a^2,\dots$ are linearly independent over $F$
3. $F$-vector space $F[a]=\{\sum_{i=0}^{n}  a_i a^i\ : a_i \in F\}$ is of finite dimension over $F$
4. $F[a]=F(a)$

I can't understand the proof of (3) $\Rightarrow$ (4):

proof.

(3) $\Rightarrow$ (4): For every $b\in F[a]$ we have $F[b]\subset F[a]$, hence $F[b]$ is of finite dimension over $F$. So, if $b\not\in F$, there are $d_i$ such that $\sum_{i=0}^{n} d_i b^i =0$, and $d_0\neq 0$. Then, $1/b=-d_0^{-1} 
\sum_{i=0}^{n} d_i b^{i-1}$ and hence $1/b \in F[b] \subset F[a]$.

I don't really get why this proves that $F[a]=F(a)$. Can someone give me an explanation?

Comment: Proved is that every $b\in F[a]-\{0\}$ has an invers.That means that $F[a]$ must be a field.

Comment: $F(a)$ is the least field which contains $F[a]$. If you show that $F[a]$ is a field, it means that every non-zero member of $F[a]$ is invertible you proved $F(a)=F[a]$.

Comment: Shouldn't point 2 be that they are linearly _dependent_ over $F$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a problem with your indices, you should have $1/b=-d_0^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^nd_ib^{i-1}$. Basically, you show that every element in $F[a]$ (which you can picture as the polynomials in $a$ over $F$) is invertible. This implies that $F(a)=F[a]$.